# Rails 3 NameError (uninitialized constant <controllerName>)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nameerror, uninitialized-constant

I get a `NameError uninitialized constant WorkoutLog` when attempting to access a non-resourceful action on a controller.

My controller looks as follows:

```
class WorkoutLogController < ApplicationController
   def index
     # random code
   end

   def on_date
     # random code
   end
end
```

My Routes File:

```
 match "workout_log/:date", :controller => "workout_log", :action => "on_date", :as => "log_on_date"
 match "workout_log", :controller => 'workout_log', :action => 'index'
```

And then I have a my link_to as such:

```
<%= link_to "View Log", log_on_date_path(:date => Date.today.strftime('%d-%B-%Y')), :remote => true, "data-type" => "html" %>
```

The WorkoutLogController has no model behind it - it's just a controller. However, I can't perform a request on the on_date because it throws the following error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant WorkoutLog):
```

When I run `rake routes` it seems to be fine as it generates the following:

```
log_on_date        /workout_log/:date(.:format)                  {:controller=>"workout_log", :action=>"on_date"}
workout_log        /workout_log(.:format)                        {:controller=>"workout_log", :action=>"index"}
```

I can't wrap my head around what the issue is (especially after spending the past night trying to figure it out). Is rails looking for a model to associate with it and failing to do so?

Comment: I've copied your code exactly as it appears here and it works for me.  Wondering if there's something extra hanging around in routes perhaps? Also, your controller should be named workout_log_controller.rb otherwise you'll get a routing error.  Not the answer you're looking for, but I hope it helps. Good luck.

Comment: The file name is workout_log_controller.rb (As you stated). That's what's got me peeved about the issue - by all accounts, it should be working, lol. I'll do some more inspecting with routes and where they are in the order or precedence. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. It had to do with declarative_authorization.
Since I had not copied the code 100%, I left out the following from my controller code pasted above:

```
filter_resource_access
```

declarative_authorization uses this for resourceful routes - which was not my case. I've since switched it to `filter_access_to :all` and it works fine.  I got to the root of the problem by creating the file `workout_log.rb` in my models:

```
class WorkoutLog
end
```

Then when I issued a request to the index and on_date actions, it gave me the error that it could not find ActiveModel methods on WorkoutLog, which in turn pointed me to the filters on the WorkoutLogController.

If you look under Examples > Controller at the [declarative_authorization page on GitHub](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization), it'll provide the necessary info.
Hope this helps anyone else who has this issue!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I was sure something else was at work there and was really curious as to what it could be.  Thanks for updating with your answer here.